# App works fine on local host and on heroku, but user data is missing on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am creating an app, and when I log in on the local host it works fine; However, when I log into the site on heroku it states the user does not exist.   Basically the app runs fine on local and also runs fine on heroku, but the user data is missing on heroku.

I ran 'run rake db:migrate'
followed by 'heroku run rake db:migrate'
and then did 'heroku restart'
followed by 'heroku open'

$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2704
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20130305200211)
Migrating to AddNameToUsers (20130306015906)
Migrating to CreatePins (20130306222042)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're expecting there to be users in your users table on Heroku, but have yet to either create any users or run `rake db:seed` (if you have any seed users).

Bear in mind that the local version of the app has an entirely independent codebase *and* database to the version of the app running on Heroku, so you should not necessarily expect to see the same data in both apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `heroku db:push`. There is a bit more detail in the blog post they published about it. Basically what it does is push your local database up to the heroku app. You might have to run `gem install taps` first.